# Me carga el css pero los @media fallan

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, express

Tengo una web con express la cosa es que cuando solo la tenia con html y css se acomodaba bien el footer y la navbar y todo el contenido, pero desde que lo pase con express ya no se enchica la navbar ni el footer y la verdad no se que hacer.

Aqui les dejo el codigo del archivo routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'First Web Node' });
});

router.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact', { title: 'Contact Page' });
});

router.get('/design/startinwebdesign', (req, res) => {
  res.render('startinwebdesign', { title: 'First Web Node' });
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

Aqui les dejo el index principal.

```
const express = require("express");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

// settings
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// middlewares
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// routes
app.use(require("./routes"));

// static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// listening the Server
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("Server on port", app.get("port"));
});
```

En si si carga el css pero es como si los @media fallaran es extraño.

En esta imagen es cuando lo subi con express y no se enchicaba correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen es cuando no usaba nada solo html y css puro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es difícil que te podamos ayudar sin código. ¿Por qué no lo cargas?

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Te sugiero revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias